# json conversion from nested array to object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript

I have json nested array as follows:

```
 Parent: {
      Child1: [
        {name:'grandchild1', value:'abc', checked:true},
        {name:'grandchild2', value:'pqr', checked:false}
      ],
      Child2: [
        {name:'grandchild3', value:'abcd', checked:false},
        {name:'grandchild4', value:'pqrs', checked:true}
      ],
parent2{...........}....
    };
```

I need to convert it into:

```
 [  
   {  
      "filename":"Parent",
      "children":[  
         {  
            "filename":"Child1",
            "children":[  
               {  
                  "filename":"grandchild1",
                  "type":"ts"
               },
               {  
                  "filename":"grandchild2",
                  "type":"ts"
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "filename":"Child2",
            "children":[  
               {  
                  "filename":"grandchild3",
                  "type":"ts"
               },
               {  
                  "filename":"grandchild4",
                  "type":"ts"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   { filename:"Parent1"..........
   },....
]
```

It is a part of angular material tree. They have sample code [Link](https://stackblitz.com/angular/goolrxyjjee?file=app%2Fcdk-tree-flat-example.ts)

Tried with below code:

```
Object.keys(obj).reduce<FileNode[]>((accumulator, key) => {
      const value = obj[key];
      const node = new FileNode();
      node.filename = key;

      if (value != null) {
        if (typeof value === 'object') {
          node.children = this.buildFileTree(value, level + 1);
        } else {
          node.type = value;
        }
      }

      return accumulator.concat(node);
    }, []);
  }
```

But not getting what I need.

Please suggest me how can I convert into the following format so that it will accept the corresponding way?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Tip: [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: `Parent` is not an array.. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi, Look at Object.values and reduce function ;)

Comment: @Maxime Giro can you give a fiddle?

Comment: The easiest way would probably be a recursive function that transforms the object if it has an array as a value (because as I see it, the leaves are objects without any arrays).

Comment: @JSHelp can you post as an answer?it will be very helpful!!

Comment: And I think that there should be a `[` instead of a `{` after `Parent` because you probably want an array of children (the brackets should be closed at the end respectively)—else it wouldn't work.

Comment: Please state what result your code gives, and how it compares to what you got. This info often allows other devs to Quickly hone in on the issue. As per SO, "But not getting what I need." is not very descriptive. State any error messages, or describe how what you got is different from what you want/expected. Thanks. It helps us efficiently help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [for of](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/for...of) and [for in](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/for...in) functions

```js
const list = {Parent1 :{
    Child1: [
      {name:'grandchild1', value:'abc', checked:true},
      {name:'grandchild2', value:'pqr', checked:false}
     ] ,
  Child2: [
   {name:'grandchild3', value:'abcd', checked:false},
   {name:'grandchild4', value:'pqrs', checked:true}
  ]
}, Parent2 :{
    Child1: [
      {name:'grandchild1', value:'abc', checked:true},
      {name:'grandchild2', value:'pqr', checked:false}
     ] ,
  Child2: [
   {name:'grandchild3', value:'abcd', checked:false},
   {name:'grandchild4', value:'pqrs', checked:true}
  ]
}};

const res = []

for(let parent in list){

let parentTemp = {
    filename : parent,
    children : []
}

  for(let child in list[parent]){

      let childTemp = {filename : child, children : []};

      for(let grandChild of list[parent][child]){
          childTemp.children.push({filename : grandChild.name, type : grandChild.value, status: grandChild.checked});
      }
      parentTemp.children.push(childTemp);


  }
  res.push(parentTemp);
}


console.log(res);
```

Comment: looking for a generalised answer, There can be multiple parents say parent1, parent2 etc...